# Accounts not available

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

My profile page is currently displaying this message under the Accounts section:

> Accounts are temporarily unavailable

I have accounts on several stackexchange sites.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: A temporary glitch most likely. Work in progress I'm guessing.

Comment: It's currently oscillating.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables no, it's caching.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - With a name like that, how can we trust you?  Then again, with a name like that, how can we trust me?

Comment: It says they're temporarily unavailable. They finally added that message in instead of just displaying "0 Accounts" for everyone and people *still* ask questions about it. Its temporary, which means **they know about it**, and it will go back to normal soon.

Comment: So it sounds like it is a feature.

Comment: All the network profile related data is temporary unavailable, I won't take it too hard probably database maintenance/crash either way it will work soon. :)

Comment: Maybe the text should be changed to "Accounts are temporarily unavailable, for a reason".

Comment: I suggest "Accounts are temporarily unavailable, due to oscillation and/or caching."

Comment: "There is text on the 'Add Comment' button which states 'Add Comment'; is this a bug or a feature?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The message is correct, I'm gonna call it a feature.

Comment: 50min man this is one long feature...

Comment: Just a note: Currently, [network profiles](http://stackexchange.com/users/89201) are *completely* unavailable, not just accounts. They are certainly doing some sort of maintenance or updates.

Comment: @ani - or some sort of twisted social experiment :P

Comment: @Lix I'm with you, this is a test of 2 things 1: how sarcastic are SO users and 2: How demanding are SO users :P I'm guessing from the comments above sarcasm is ranking near a 10 out of 10.

Comment: No juicy details this time about what happened behind the scenes? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it was time for a network aggregator backfill and it had some hiccups...we made substantial improvements for speed as a result though, duration should be much shorter next round.