# Unable to comment on Stack Overflow question or answer

Tags: bug

I find myself unable to comment on questions or answers on Stack Overflow today. My reputation is 53K, so it's not a problem with insufficient reputation.

Is something currently broken with the authorization / authentication system?

**EDIT**

I was getting an error to the effect *User lacks permission*. Now I am getting a different error,

> An error occured during comment submission

**Update**

I was just now able to submit a comment. Hopefully the issue is fixed and not just transiently working.

**Another update**

It could not submit a second comment. It seems the issue remains.

Comment: I can't check because it says *Accounts are temporarily unavailable*. Perhaps things are broken?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not getting that error.  Indeed, I seem logged in and can check my profile page.  But certainly may be related.

Comment: They may do some updates - (the same here).

Comment: See [Accounts not available](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168517)