# Flair is not seeing accounts

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

This keeps happening lately but not permanently with the flair.

Is this an issue?

[image: Wrong flair]

Comment: How does this happen? Are you talking about global flair?

Comment: @hims056 Yup; same with mine as Eduard's. \*sniff\*

Comment: Very possibly related to [this recent issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168517/accounts-not-available)

Comment: Deleted the answer as it is not showing flairs sometimes :)

Comment: @Lix: I'm 100% certain it is related to that issue. No accounts available means no flair calculation either.

Comment: That's not duplicate of that other report; might be same root problem but  different issue caused by it. If you ask me, the flair should also show the same message when the accounts are not available. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API which we pull these from was undergoing maintenance yesterday that lasted far longer than expected.  Out of that are 2 notes:

1. We *very* rarely need to do a maintenance like this, only a major interruption in service  causes a need.
2. We made substantial speed improvements on the process so future outages will be far less in duration.

Flair should be back to normal now, if you have a specific example of cache that needs purging , I'll handle that manually - just comment here.