# Accounts are temporarily unavailable: add a link to a notice explanation

Tags: feature-request, error-message, outage

I have read [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118201/network-profile-information-reporting-temporarily-unavailable) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168517/accounts-not-available) about the message being self-sufficient... but it really isn't.  Even moderators are in the dark, and the message given reads like a generic error.

Suggestion: Add a link to some help section stating

> Why are Accounts are temporarily unavailable?
>
> There is a known outage occurring currently, the account list will be available soon.

Or something to the sorts.

> Power-down of our Oregon data center is starting, if you see any issues we actually appreciate you yelling at us :)

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/379659432827031552

Comment: I was just confused by this. For a second I thought someone had got a stack exchange wide ban

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very rare *temporary* occurrence, we don't feel that additional explanation is really necessary since things will be back to normal shortly after seeing it.

The import of Social Sound Design from SE 1.0 necessitates a network aggregate level backfill which was just run for the users portion, given it was the last SE 1.0 site...I don't think that reason will come up again :)

Also just for clarification: that tweet was mostly unrelated, we just opted to do the user backfill at the network level before pulling the Oregon SQL servers offline (due to the massive log generation a backfill causes, that would pend on the NYC disks until Oregon replicas could absorb it).